# problema con listas y bucle while

Tags: python

soy nuevo en programación y estoy intentando crear una lista pero esta solo me guarda el ultimo dato que puse en el bucle cual es mi error?

```
rojo=[]
azul=[]
while True:
    try:
        valor=int(input("ingrese valor: "))
        print("1-ETIQUETA ROJA")
        print("2-ETIQUETA AZUL")
        op=int(input("INGRESE OPCION: "))
        opc=str(input("INGRESE salir PARA CONTINUAR "))
        if(opc=="salir"):
            break
    except:
        print("SOLO NUMEROS...")
if(op==1):
    rojo.append(valor)
if(op==2):
    azul.append(valor)

print(rojo)
print(azul)
```

Comment: El append está fuera del ciclo `while` por tal razón los valores siempre se reemplazan y solo te queda el último, pon esos `if` dentro del `while`

Answer (score 0):

Tienes las cosas un poco descolocadas. Tambien seguramente tampoco te hace falta pasar todas las opciones a `int` y no es necesario pasar a `str` lo que devuelva el `input` ya que de por sí lo es.

```
rojo=[]
azul=[]
while True:
    try:
        valor=int(input("ingrese valor: "))
        print("1-ETIQUETA ROJA")
        print("2-ETIQUETA AZUL")
        op =input("INGRESE OPCION: ")

        if(op=='1'):
            rojo.append(valor)
        elif(op=='2'):
            azul.append(valor)

        if 'salir' == input("INGRESE salir PARA CONTINUAR "):
            break
    except:
        print ( "SOLO NUMEROS..." )

print(rojo)
print(azul)
```